Include additional row-metadata when querying EF Core entities
In a SQL Server database queried via EF Core 6, I have an entity type MyEntity like this:
class MyEntity 
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int ParentId { get; set; }
    MyEntity Parent { get; set; } 
    List<SomeOtherEntity> OtherData { get; set; }
}

This means it's a tree hierarchy of entities. When I search this table for entities matching a certain name, I use a really complex CTE query to fetch the set of records matching some search criteria and their parent records, all in one go. This works well.
Example, matching entities with the name '%Bob%' can match two records, and includes an additional third record, which was included because it was the parent record of record Id=1.
Level     Id     Name     ParentId
----------------------------------
0          1     Bob      4
0          3     Bobby    null
1          4     Joe      null

However, I'd like to convey back to the caller which rows were included due to match and which were merely included because they were parents. I have this information available after the SQL query in the "Level" column which indicates if the row was matched (Level = 0) or included as a parent (Level > 0).
The problem is that my entity type does not have a property Level  so I can't pass this information back in the entity. I also can't use a non-entity record, because I want to continue composing the query by doing .Include(e => e.SomeOtherData) for the entity rows returned.
How can I pass the level value for each entity back to the caller while still keeping the possibility to compose the entity further?

EF Core knows nothing about the CTE or levels. You'll have to either return the Level explicitly or calculate it by traversing the loaded objects. BTW EF Core 6 reaches End Of Life in a few of weeks. EF Core 8 added support for hierarchyid. You can avoid the complex recursive CTE by using the far faster hierarchyid type, map it to a property and use hierarchyId.GetLevel()

The table is the result of a search-type query so deciding whether the objects are included due to match (level 0) in code means re-doing/duplicating the search process again, which I'd like to avoid. Returning the level explicitly is what I'd like do. but I don't want to repeat the query that produced the table more than once.
I mean I can hack this by stuffing it into the name in my query so its Bob/0 and Joe/1, then fixing those up afterwards which would be more efficient than traversing.
Sadly hierarchyid won't work for this use case. EFCore8 non-entity record queries might.

If you upgrade at least to EF Core 7, it is possible to use SqlQuery to acomplish your needs but with additional manipulations.

You haven't posted any code so we can't guess what's going on. You don't need to repeat anything in a recursive CTE to generate the level. The efficient thing is to use EF Core 8 and HierarchyID. After all, you'll have to migrate very soon. Beyond that, you'll have to traverse the objects. Traversing 10, even 1000 objects on the client is more efficient than an inefficient SQL query that causes full table scans. There are several SO answers showing how to traverse a tree of objects

The query to fetch the rows extremely complex and also uses a versioned hierarchy where records have record-revisions and can have different hierarchy at different points in time. All that complexity is hidden in a table valued funcion search(searchTerm, asOfVersion). It's possible that hierarchyid could solve it (Not trivially though), but EF8 is still further away than the need to resolve this. The quickest workaround I found is this: the entity has a deleted bit. In any search result deleted=0 of course. So I can re-use that bit to convey whether level is 0 or > 0, for search results.

Maybe i'm missing something, but why can't you add a property called Level?

The level is a result of the query not a property of the entity. If the record is a "search hit" that will be displayed, it's level 0.  But included in the result table are also all ancestors of the hits (See 'Joe' in example). They are needed for some other display purposes but won't be in the main result table. So the same entity can be a Level 0 result in one search (If I search for %Jo%) but a level 1 result in another (When I search for %Bob%).
